# VBA Excel Declaring xlValues as a parameter in a sub

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a reusable sub to copy a column to another column. In this case, I want to add a third variable to choose the type of PasteSpecial. Right now it is xlValues and only paste values. I am hoping to make it more versatile: values, format, formula... all kinds of paste specials.

What I want to know is how to declare this as a parameter, and will excel accept it as a parameter. 
Is there like a dictionary I can look up the type of these things?

```
   Sub copyPasteColumn(column1 As String, column2 As String)
    'just paste 1 column to another, values only

        Sheets("BILLING DATA").Columns(column1).Copy
        Columns(column2).PasteSpecial xlValues

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another parameter [XlPasteType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx):

```
Sub CopyColumn(ByVal col1 As String, ByVal col2 As String, ByVal xOperType As XlPasteType)
    'here your code
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
CopyColumn "A", "B", xlPasteComments 'or any other type of `XlPasteType`
```

More details at: [Range.PasteSpecial Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx)

Comment: And you could make it optional and provide a default value, if you want: `Optional ByVal xOperType As XlPasteType = xlPasteValues`.

Comment: so does xlPasteType supposed to be a string? or it just parse whatever word in that position.

Comment: @knt5784, try to find out ;) Tip: it accepts value from `XlPasteType` enumeration. When you start writing the third parameter, the code editor will display combo at this position...

Answer (score 0):

This will show the PasteType in an Intellisense kind of way, if you don't select a PasteType then Values are pasted by default.

Edit - this uses column numbers rather than letters - column A = 1, etc, but can just as easily use your method of letters.

```
Enum PasteType
    xlPasteAll = -4104                          'Everything will be pasted.
    xlPasteAllExceptBorders = 7                 'Everything except borders will be pasted.
    xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats = 14    'Everything will be pasted and conditional formats will be merged.
    xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme = 13             'Everything will be pasted using the source theme.
    xlPasteColumnWidths = 8                     'Copied column width is pasted.
    xlPasteComments = -4144                     'Comments are pasted.
    xlPasteFormats = -4122                      'Copied source format is pasted.
    xlPasteFormulas = -4123                     'Formulas are pasted.
    xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats = 11        'Formulas and Number formats are pasted.
    xlPasteValidation = 6                       'Validations are pasted.
    xlPasteValues = -4163                       'Values are pasted.
    xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats = 12
End Enum

Sub copyPasteColumn(column1 As Long, column2 As Long, Optional lType As PasteType = xlPasteValues)

        Sheets("BILLING DATA").Columns(column1).Copy
        Columns(column2).PasteSpecial lType

End Sub

Sub Test()

    copyPasteColumn 1, 2, xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you post an answer if this answer is exactly the same as mine?

Comment: You posted it while I was still writing it - it isn't exactly the same as your either.  Yours is better - doesn't use the ENUM, just the XlPasteType.

Was about to edit mine to say as much, but you jumped on me before I had a chance....

Comment: Sorry, but it wasn't my intention to "jump on you". I didn't say that your answer is worse than mine or even my answer is better than yours. As to the answer: `XlPasteType` is embeded enumeration, why to define custom?

Comment: Because you learn something new every day.  That's why I defined it and why I think your answer is better - you knew not to define it and I didn't. (in my opinion your answer is better suited).